# change roles of general purpose I/O of my system

Tags: embedded-linux

how can I change some linux system roles of its items ?

Comment: I'm only used to the low end Cortex M parts of the SAM, but at least those have a painful and user-unfriedly router functionality through a register called PMUX (it may or may not have the same name on SAMA parts). You have to check the routing tables for the magic number to write into the PMUX register for the port, or nothing will work. Best bet is to find some example code or app note for your specific part and see how they set such registers there. Everyone using these parts struggle with this.

Answer (score 1):

As I replied to you on IRC, you can simply remove line 101 or the whole isc node, that will ensure the isc is not muxing the pins. The question you are not really answering is how will you use those GPIOS, will you write a kernel driver or use libgpio?

If you want to write a kernel driver, then you will have to learn about the device tree soon if you want to get your driver to probe.

Comment: You don't if you are using libgpio and not the usual button and led frameworks.

Comment: It is a problem if you are trying to use gpio-keys. I'm still not clear whether you are going to use the input and led framework or use libgpio from userspace. Which pin are you trying to use as a button ?